# Middleware triggering once response send

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to trigger some function once after response has been sent to client for that am using the following code, But `res.on('end'` not triggering at all.So what I am missing here, or else any other efficient way to achieve this?

```
 app.use(function(req, res, next) {
      res.on('end', function() {
        console.log('end') ; //Portsion need to execute once response send
      })

      next();
    })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the last versions of node.js the correct event to watch for `end` or `close` actions is `finish` ([documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_finish)). So your code should be

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.on('finish', function() {
    console.log('end') ;
  })

  next();
})
```